# How to prove that $\|u_n^{\prime}\|_{\infty}\le 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

Consider the sequence $$u_n(t)=\sqrt{(t-1)^2 +\frac{1}{n}}.$$
I need to understand if
$\|u_n^{\prime}\|_{\infty}\le 1$.

Firstly, $u_n^{\prime}(t)$ stands for the first derivative of $u_n$ made with respect to $t$, isn't it?

If yes, it should be
$$u_n^{\prime}(t) =(t-1)\left((t-1)^2 +\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-1/2}.$$

Thus, how to show that $\|u_n^{\prime}\|_{\infty}\le 1$?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the fact that $(t-1)^{2}+\frac  1n \geq (t-1)^{2}$ and $(t-1)^{2})^{-1/2} =\frac  1 {|t-1|}$so $|u_n'(t) |\leq |\frac {t-1} {t-1}|=1$.